# Firebase .getIdToken() returns invalid token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make just a simple authentication app with electron and firebase redirect, but if the user is already logged in and I use the  `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` to get the IdToken of that user, but when i try that token in
`firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)` I get the error that says **ERROR: auth/invalid-credential**

Here is my code front-end

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( async function (user) {
if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
  var user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (user != null) {
     await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
       window.location.href = "electron://"+idToken;
     }).catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error)
     });
    

  }

} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

}
});
```

Here is my code back-end

```
app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    if (commandLine[2]) {
      var url = commandLine[2].split('/')
      var id_token = url[2]
      console.log('id: ', id_token)

      // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
      var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((success)=>{
        myWindow.loadFile('./scr/welcome.html')
        console.log('RESULT: ',success)
      })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log('ERROR:', errorMessage)
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          console.log('ERROR:', credential)
          // ...
        })
      
    }
```

I'm missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how ID tokens work.  The purpose of an ID token is to pass to your backend, so that it can validate the identity of the signed in user, and perform some action on their behalf.  It's not valid for signing in on the client again.  You might want to review the [documentation on use of ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to learn how this works.

`signInWithCredential` only works with Google Auth when you correctly construct a GoogleAuthProvider credential.  There is plenty of sample code in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider) for that.

Comment: Oh, I see, I will check the documentation and see how it works, Thanks!!

Comment: I got it it working now with admin SDK, thanks again for the explanation !